# Rails 3.2: Replace null values with empty string from json serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2 [serialization](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) to convert ruby object to json.

For Example, I have serialized ruby object to following json

```
{
  "relationship":{
    "type":"relationship",
    "id":null,
    "followed_id": null
  }
}
```

Using following serialize method in my class Relationship <  [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  {
   :type        => 'relationship',
   :id          => id,
   :followed_id => followed_id
  }
end
```

I need to replace null values with empty strings i.e. empty double quotes, in response json.

How can I achieve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: why do what to do that, what problem do you see further if it has nil?

Comment: Objective C does not recognize null as a special string like true/false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813910/285614)

```
def as_json(opts={})
  json = super(opts)
  Hash[*json.map{|k, v| [k, v || ""]}.flatten]
end
```

-- Edit --

As per jdoe's comment, if you only want to include some fields in your json response, I prefer doing it as:

```
def as_json(opts={})
  opts.reverse_merge!(:only => [:type, :id, :followed_id])
  json = super(opts)
  Hash[*json.map{|k, v| [k, v || ""]}.flatten]
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this lead to appearing ALL the attributes in json (which is obviously not what the author wants)? I'm about the first line. The second one looks impeccable.

Comment: cool, thanks! currently as_json is implemented in all activeRecord classes. Is there any way to put this method to parent class i.e. ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: This won't work if the value v is false. As a result, any boolean fields you have that are false will get converted to "". You can instead do:

    Hash[*json.map{|k, v| [k, (v.nil? ? "" : v)]}.flatten]

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the problem here. Just make it via `||` operator:

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  {
   :type        => 'relationship',
   :id          => id || '',
   :followed_id => followed_id || ''
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks jdoe, Actually I want some generic code for all objects serialization

Answer (score 0):

using below method you will get modified hash or json object. it will replace blank string with nill. need to pass the hash in parameter.

```
def json_without_null(json_object)
  if json_object.kind_of?(Hash)
    json_object.as_json.each do |k, v|
      if v.nil?
        json_object[k] = ""
      elsif  v.kind_of?(Hash)
        json_object[k] = json_without_null(v)
      elsif v.kind_of?(Array)
        json_object[k] = v.collect{|a|  json_without_null(a)}
      end
    end
  end
  json_object
end
```