# to_json returns nil in a field if its black, ios can't interpret that null in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How to change the field values from null to "" in the output of to_json?

It currently returns

```
{"name":"priya","mobile":null}
```

instead I want

```
{"name":"priya","mobile":""}
```

or

```
{"name":"priya","mobile":"NA"}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {"name" => "pryia", "mobile" => nil} 

Hash[*s.map{|k, v| [k, v || "NA"]}.flatten]
# => "name"=>"pryia", "mobile"=>"NA"}

Hash[*s.map{|k, v| [k, v || "NA"]}.flatten].to_json
# => "{\"name\":\"pryia\",\"mobile\":\"NA\"}"
```

Comment: didnt work for me. i want null should be replaced with "" or "NA". With no slashes as well.

Comment: There actually are no slashes. to_json in the console will have slashes to escape the quotes. 

> puts Hash[*s.map{|k, v| [k, v || "NA"]}.flatten].to_json
{"name":"pryia","mobile":"NA"}

Answer (score 1):

To add to philee's answer, you could add an as_json method to your model.

```
def as_json(opts={})
  json = super(opts)
  Hash[*json.map{|k, v| [k, v || "NA"]}.flatten]
end
```